# wkhtmltopdf create pdf with opened details

Tags: html, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

I got an HTML with a button *show details* which opens up a lot of information.

I need to convert that page into pdf, therefore I use wkhtmltopdf.

The problem is in the PDF the details won't show up because the button wasn't clicked.

The second problem is I can't change the html because it is automatically generated by a tool called OpenSCAP. Maybe you got an idea how I can show this details in the pdf?

I'm working on SLES 11.

my command is

```
wkhtmltopdf --enable-forms sivop.html sivop.pdf
```

Comment: use jsPDF instead

Comment: as i said i cant modify the HTML i use wkhtmltopdf from the command line